# "I'm Marsh Turner called."

Tags: syntactic-analysis, dialects, speech, southern-white-vernacular-english

From the movie *Cross Creek*, set in 1920s' Florida.

> Marsh: I'm Marsh Turner called. This is my daughter Ellie.

The syntax of this line (as opposed to the standard "I am called Marsh Turner") strikes me as interesting. Is this construction in doing introductions a Southernism? I have not heard this locution.

Comment: Beowulf: “The demon grim was Grendel called . . .”

Comment: It sounds as if he is Marsh and here to tell you that Turner called. Apart from that the usage harks back to German. "Only Germans are so discourteous to their verbs." *A Scandal in Bohemia*